# dataset view and access control in yaml file

Tags: intake

I am new to intake and I am trying to understand how I can control the visibility and access  rights for catalog entries. For example I would like to find out how a catalog yaml file looks like for the following case, suppose I have two csv files to which I provide access through a catalog yaml file together with two users. How can I make only one csv visible to one user while the other user can see both files? Or how would I need to change the yml file below to accomplish this?

```
metadata:
        version: 1
        description: "lattice data catalog"

sources:
        sample1:
            driver: csv
            args:
                 urlpath: test1.csv
        testcsv:
            driver: csv
            args:
                 urlpath: test2.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's specify that this is in the context of the Intake server. You *could* build a YAML catalog driver which could only present some entries to a user based on some environment variable or other information, but we'll not consider that here.

The general outline for creating an auth plugin for the server is given [in the docs](https://intake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auth-plugins.html#server-side). In that case, a header string is compared to a single static secret. In your case, the key information will be passed by your authenticating proxy. You could compare the user to some explicit input drawn from an external source:

```
def allow_access(self, header, source, catalog):
    user = header.get("X-user-from-nginx", None)
    source_name = source.describe()['name']
    if source_name == "sample1":
        return user in ['user1', 'user2']
    if source_name == "sample2":
        return user in ['user2']
    return False
```

or you could embed the permissions into the catalog (which will *only* make sense when read via your server with the given auth)

```
sources:
  sample1:
    driver: csv
    args:
      urlpath: test1.csv
    metadata:
      allow_users: ["user1"]
```

with auth plugin

```
def allow_access(self, header, source, catalog):
    user = header.get("X-user-from-nginx", None)
    allowed = source.describe().get("metadata", {}).get('allow_users', [])
    return user in allowed
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I got this working. One comment for Nginx in reverse proxy. I had to add the line `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-User $remote_user` to my location to be able to pass the username to the intake server.

Comment: Yes, and in general, different specific configuration will be needed for each proxy type and setup.